# Как расширить координатную плоскость QCustomPlot

Tags: c++, qt, графики

У меня есть координатная плоскость QCustomPlot, она выглядит так: [image: плоскость, отображаемая у меня]

Я хочу чтобы была не одна, а все 4 четверти плоскости. Например так: [image: я хотел бы, чтобы было так:]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: QCustomPlot так не умеет. Посмотрите их примеры. Положение осей всегда будет по краям графика. Кстати возможно и верхнюю ось добавить и правую. А начало координат (левый нижний угол) не обязательно (0,0) Его можно поставить (-14,-8), как это сделано у Вас.